# Assistance using expo-camera

Tags: ios, react-native, camera, expo

I'm trying to make it so when I push a button in my app (being run through expo) it will prompt the user's camera. They will then be able to take a photo and it'll be saved in the app.

I found two guides online; both work but not how I need.

One guide will just have the camera running, not hidden behind the button, as if it was a part of the app. Link here.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/camera/

The other guide makes a button available, but it will only take up as much camera space as you allotted for it. Link here
https://github.com/hayanisaid/expo-camera-tutorial/blob/master/App.tsx

Has anyone been able to make expo-camera work like this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is:

1. Create a stack navigator
2. Put the page that you want to have the button in the stack navigator
3. Put the camera in its own page, in the stack navigator
4. Create an onPress command that when you push the button, it'll take you to the camera

Comment: So sorry for the late reply; I did this, and it worked. But I need the photo to be put in the screen before I push the button to open the camera. How would I do something like that?